# creating models/views in mvc 3 for CRUD for nested classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Creating CRUD for classes which have primitives is simple and the forms are generated automatically, but I want to create views and controllers for CRUD operations on classes which have one or more lists of other classes as their members.

for eg (not a good/actual model but works for an example),

```
class Student {
    int id;
    string name;
    string dob;
    list<ClassDetails> classes
}

class ClassDetails {
    int id;
    int name;
    string teacherName;
}
```

How can I create a view manually or through scaffolding so that the page has a box for the name, dob and then allows a user to select "add" or something similar and add an arbitrary number of class-details on the same page and then hit 'submit'?

I tried creating a class in this manner but it creates different views/controllers for students and ClassDetails, and not on the same page. Are their any sample projects or tutorials that show how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Steve Sanderson has a great scaffolding implementation that can help you and [describes it thoroughly here.](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/)

Comment: I just read through that and I still dont think that really covers what i want. From his tutorial, I am looking to do something like creating a team, and in the same page, adding players to the team without creating them beforehand. I might have to play with it a bit more to see what it can do.

Comment: This implementation will generate repository classes that will automatically help you save your "teammates" to a database without having to create them before hand. You'll get a form with the properties of your model that you can fill out and click save.

Comment: What I meant was to have the properties for the team on the form and underneath them, on the same form, have a row of properties for teammates with a button to keep adding rows to keep adding more teammates to that team, without having to go to a different form to create the teammates

Comment: It sounds like your concern is really more about the UI.  Steve also made an outstanding javascript framework in MVVM that would help you out a great deal.  It's called Knockout.JS:  http://knockoutjs.com/.  As long as you have your server-side code set up to receive and serve JSON, than you can use Knockout to make your UI however you want.  Go to the tutorials, and check out the one on saving data to the server.